# Compare and subtract the records 2 Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, subtraction

i have 2 tables (each two tables have the same structure)
i get the sum of two table with bellow code.
now i want to find Sum of the records from the previous month and Sum of the current month, and Compare they.
If the sum of the previous month is greater than the sum of the current month Records to be selected.If not, is not selected

```
Table 1                                        Table 2<br>
StudentId=1  Score=50 Date =2017/01/01      StudentId= 1 Score=100 Date =2017/01/01<br>
StudentId=1  Score=20 Date =2017/02/01      StudentId= 1 Score=10 Date =2017/02/01<br>
StudentId=2  Score=60 Date =2017/01/01      StudentId= 2 Score=100 Date =2017/01/01<br>
StudentId=2  Score=540 Date =2017/02/01     StudentId= 2 Score=100 Date =2017/02/01<br>
```

Current Result:

```
StudentId       HighScoreUser<br>
1               180<br>
2               800<br>
---------------------------------<br>
```

Result that i want :

```
StudentId   Prev Month(2017/01/01)  Current Month(2017/02/01)<br>
1           150                     30<br>
2           160                     640<br>
```

1 --> 150 > 30  -->True? --> Yes, So must be selected

### 2 --> 160 > 640 -->True? --> No, So must be not selected

Result (selected values) = StudentId , (Sum prev Month - Sum Current Month)

```
<br>`CREATE PROCEDURE SelectTopMonth
    @Date1  NVARCHAR(12),
    @Date2  NVARCHAR(12)
AS
    SELECT StudentId, ISNULL(SUM(Score),0) As HighScoreUser
FROM (SELECT StudentId, Score FROM tbl_ActPoint     WHERE Date >= @Date1    AND     Date <= @Date2
      UNION ALL
      SELECT StudentId, Score FROM tbl_EvaPoint     WHERE Date >= @Date1    AND     Date <= @Date2
     ) as T 
GROUP BY  StudentId ORDER BY HighScoreUser DESC
RETURN 0`
```

[image]

Comment: There is something not compatible in your question, there is student id 2 within **Result that you want** and **within your explanation** you said about student id 2 > So must be not selected, how come ?

Comment: id not! sum1 > Sum2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lead analytical function of SQL Server in order to get your result.

**TABLE1**

```
create table table1 
(
  studentid integer,
  score integer,
  date date
);

insert into table1 values(1,50,'2017/01/01'); 
insert into table1 values(1,20,'2017/02/01');
insert into table1 values(2,60,'2017/01/01');
insert into table1 values(2,540,'2017/02/01');
```

**TABLE2**

```
create table table2
(
  studentid integer,
  score integer,
  date date
);
insert into table2 values(1,100,'2017/01/01'); 
insert into table2 values(1,10,'2017/02/01');
insert into table2 values(2,100,'2017/01/01');
insert into table2 values(2,100,'2017/02/01');
```

**Query:**

```
with data  as (
select table1.studentid , (table1.score + table2.score) as pre_score, table1.date,
lead((table1.score + table2.score),1) over(partition by table1.studentid order by table1.studentid,table1.date) 
as cur_score
from table1 join table2 
on table1.studentid = table2.studentid 
and table1.date = table2.date
)
select * from data
where cur_score is not null 
and pre_score > cur_score
```

Added this condition as per your comment "and pre_score > cur_score".

Comment: yes i tried this, query work on your table but not work on my table i think something is wrong.i editied my question and added tables structure and result

Comment: Why you have date column as nvarvhar ? What is wrong in your data ?

Comment: for cutome date type i used navarchar

Comment: you can see result that only returned studentId 14 , and cur_Score is wrong.

Comment: You have to add table structure at the start when you have asked question. Is it possible to have different date as well in same month for same student id.

Comment: with data as (select studentid, month(convert(date , date)) as month ,month(convert(date , date)) as year ,sum(score) as score from (
select * from table1 
union all 
select * from table2 
) a 
group by studentid, month, year ) 
select studentid, score as pre_score, lead(score, 1) over(partition by studentid order by studentid, year, month ) as cur_score
from data , Try this psuedo code in this we I am summing all score based on month and year and then utilizing lead function to get result. There might be syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to see data as below:

```
Select StudentId, [2017/01/01] as [Prev Month(2017/01/01)],
                  [2017/02/01] as [Current Month(2017/02/01)] from (
    Select * from t1
    Union all
    Select * from t2
    ) a
    pivot (sum([Score]) for [Date] in ([2017/01/01],[2017/02/01]) ) p
    Where [2017/01/01] > [2017/02/01]
```